# How to install basic modules for MSYS Perl?

Tags: perl, module, cpan, autoconf, msys2

I need to use the [MSYS Perl](http://repo.msys2.org/msys/x86_64) to be able to install autoconf on my MSYS2 on Windows 7 because ActivePerl or Strawberry Perl don't work for the autoconf installation. The only problem is the default installation of MSYS Perl doesn't seem to include some basic modules such as `strict` or `Carp`. When I make autoconf it gives:

> Can't locate Carp.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Carp module) (@INC contains: ../lib /usr/local/perl-5.22.1/lib/perl5/core_perl /usr/local/perl-5.22.1/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/local/perl-5.22.1/lib/perl5/vendor_perl

When I try to do a manual installation of `Carp`, during the `perl Makefile.PL` step I get:

> Can't locate warnings.pm in @INC

The problem is, in order to install the `warnings.pm` I need to have installed the basic set of modules such as `strict` but those modules don't seem to be present in the core modules directory `/usr/local/perl-5.22.1/lib/perl5/core_perl`

How can I install those basic modules for my MSYS Perl?

Comment: Just my $0.02, but `/usr/local/` doesn't sound like you are calling `/usr/bin/perl.exe` from the MSYS2 Perl package...

Comment: FYI: when printing `@INC` under MSYS2 on my WIndows 10 machine I only get paths under `/usr/lib/perl5` and `/usr/share/perl5`.

Comment: @StefanBecker Thank you for the comment. I have installed the MSYS Perl into a new directoryunder /usr/local on purpose in order to be able to switch to the ActiveState's Perl when I need to. And I defined this new Perl into MSYS's .bash_profile like so `export PERL5=/usr/local/perl-5.22.1 && PATH=$PATH:$PERL5/bin` and I of course erased the ActiveState's Perl path from Windows System Environment Variables. This setup works quite fine under the MSYS environment.

Comment: To define the Perl modules' directory I entered those lines into ~/.bash_profile `export PERL5LIB=$PERL5/lib/perl5/vendor_perl"${PERL5LIB:+:$PERL5LIB}"`
`export PERL5LIB=$PERL5/lib/perl5/site_perl"${PERL5LIB:+:$PERL5LIB}"`
`export PERL5LIB=$PERL5/lib/perl5/core_perl"${PERL5LIB:+:$PERL5LIB}"` and that seems to work fine too.

Comment: Hacking and "shooting yourself in the foot" go hand-in-hand most of the time :-) Glad you got your problem solved. Probably you should close/delete your question.

Comment: This setup works fine as long as there are no modules being used. The problem is how to install any modules on this setup.

Comment: Is the autoconf package that's installable through msys2 not working?

Comment: And the version of perl in my msys2 installation is 5.28.1. Have you not run a `pacman -Syu` in years or something?

Comment: And of course none of your paths make sense. What do you think "MSYS Perl" is and how are you installing it? It doesn't appear to be via the usual way.

Comment: @Romario: if your "requirement to switch" is static, how about installing msys2 perl package with `pacman` and then making `/usr/bin/perl` a symlink that you can switch? You might even want to look into using `alternatives` system for that.

Comment: Another option might be to to use regular msys2 perl installation and `PERL=/usr/bin/perl5.22.1 ./autoconf.sh`.

Comment: @Shawn Thank you for the comment. The autoscan command doesn't seem to work, when the autoconf is installed from the msys2 repository. That's why I wanted to install autconf from scratch.

Comment: @Shawn I don't use pacman because it installs redundant software. But now I will try  it to see if it helps. I 'll try it after the dinner time.

Comment: You *don't use* the package manager the whole setup is built around and intended to work with.... Ooookay. That goes a long ways towards explaining why you're having really weird issues.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I install your `perl` module in `msys2`:

```
$ pacman -S perl-Carp-Clan
```

Here is a full list of the `perl` packages available for `msys2`:

https://packages.msys2.org/group/perl-modules